# What is the plot of $f(x) = 1 + \sqrt{\log_{10}\cos(2\pi x)}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, graphing-functions

I'm inspecting a function as in the title, and tried to plot it and then compare my result with graphing tools which lead me to confusion.

> Is it true that the plot of $f(x) = 1 + \sqrt{\log_{10}\cos(2\pi x)}$ is just a set of points $(x, y) = (n, 1); \; n \in \mathbb Z$

Inspecting the domain one may see that
$$
\log_{10}\cos(2\pi x) \ge 0 \iff \cos(2\pi x) \ge 1
$$

But $\cos x \in [-1, 1]$ therefore $\cos(2\pi x)$ must be equal to $1$ in order to satisfy the above, and that is only possible in $x \in \mathbb Z$.

The reason I'm asking is because neither Desmos nor W|A is plotting it the way i expected.

Comment: Perhaps they are plotting an imaginary component, $i\sqrt{-\log_{10}\cos(2\pi x)}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right: the domain of $f$ is the set $ \mathbb Z$ and the graph of $f$ is given by

$ \{(x,f(x)): x \in \mathbb Z\}=\{(n,1): n \in \mathbb Z\}$.